# Converting WAV to M4A using c# NAudio

Tags: c#, wav, asp.net-web-api, naudio, m4a

I want to convert a WAV file into a **M4A** file.

I could not find any reference or any example of how to achieve that.
Naudio should do the trick i assume, but i havent figured out how to do this yet.

I am writing a WebAPI2 project, and i need to return an m4a audio file to the user upon request. Been using a **PushStreamContent** in order to provide the user with the file, but using an MP3 as the conversion target, lead to many difficulties with browser support and Seek/Pause/Stop support.

Thanks in advance,
Nokky.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

M4A files simply contain AAC encoded audio. Have a look at the Media Foundation Encoder demo in the NAudio WPF demo application to see an example of using `MediaFoundationEncoder` to create AAC files. It will let you encode as aac if you have an appropriate Media Foundation Codec on your machine (you should have with Win 7 and above, although note that it doesn't do low bitrates).